# Match pattern not preceded by character

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make my regex match a pattern only if it is not preceded by a character, the `^` (circumflex) in my case.

My regex:
    `/[^\^]\w+/g`

Text to test it on:
    `Test: ^Anotherword`

Matches: "Test" and " Anotherword", even though the latter is preceded by a circumflex. Which I was trying to prevent by inserting the `[^\^]` at the start. So I'm not only trying to not match the circumflex, but also the word that comes after it. " Anotherword" should not be matched.

`[^\^]` - This is what should stop the regex from matching if an accent circonflexe is in front of it.

`\w+` - Match any word that is not preceded by a circumflex.

I cannot use lookbehind because of JavaScript limitations.

Comment: `([^^]|^)\w+` then if need be, write back `$1` on a replace. No, it works, but it's matching `T`, then `est`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, am I doing something wrong? http://regexr.com/3e855

Comment: Use `([^^\w]|^)\w+` see http://regexr.com/3e85b It basically ingects a word boundary.

Comment: Yeah so, injects a word boundary while excluding the `^` as well. `[^\w]` = `\W\b\w` Otherwise `[^^]` will match a '^`T`' and `\w+` will match `est` You can see it if you put capture groups around it.

Comment: That worked, thanks, you should post it as the official answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `([^^\w]|^)\w+`
(see http://regexr.com/3e85b)

It basically injects a word boundary while excluding the ^ as well.
`[^\w] = \W\b\w`

Otherwise `[^^]` will match a '^`T`'
and `\w+` will match `est`.

You can see it if you put capture groups around it.

Comment: Used it for this `/([^^\-\.\d])(\-?(\d+\.)?\d+\*\-?(\d+\.)?\d+)/g`, the thing I actually wanted to work, and it works using your solution. It worked without adding the `|^` though, could you explain what that does?

Comment: Sure, in JS, when using  `(something|^)` in place of a lookbehind, it reads something _OR_ beginning of string/line. Lets it match at the beginning where no character is behind it. This would simulate, for example with an negative lookbehind, `(?<!A)` where the beginning of line `^` would be satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

If matching is not strictly forbidden.

`(?:\^\w+)|(\w+)`: matches both expressions but no group is generated for `^Anotherworld`.

- `(?:\^\w+)`: matches `^Kawabanga` but no group is generated.
- `(\w+)`: everything else for grouping.

I case you want `^Anotherworld` to have a group simply remove `?:`.

Comment: That would work, but I was really looking for something that wouldn't match the second one (`^Anotherword`)

Answer (score 0):

With the growing adoption of the [ECMAScript 2018 standard](https://262.ecma-international.org/9.0/), it makes sense to also consider the lookbehind approach:

```js
const text = "One Test: ^Anotherword";

// Extracing words not preceded with ^:
console.log(text.match(/\b(?<!\^)\w+/g)); // => [ "One", "Test" ]

// Replacing words not preceded with ^ with some other text:
console.log(text.replace(/\b(?<!\^)\w+/g, '<SPAN>$&</SPAN>'));
// => <SPAN>One</SPAN> <SPAN>Test</SPAN>: ^Anotherword
```

The `\b(?<!\^)\w+` regex matches one or more word chars (`\w+`) that have no word char (letter, digit or `_`) immediately on the left (achieved with a word boundary, `\b`) that have no `^` char immediately on the left (achieved with the negative lookbehind `(?<!\^)`). Note that `^` is a special regex  metacharacter that needs to be escaped if one wants to match it as a literal caret char.

For older JavaScript environments, it is still necessary to use a workaround:

```js
var text = "One Test: ^Anotherword";

// Extracing words not preceded with ^:
var regex = /(?:[^\w^]|^)(\w+)/g, result = [],  m;
while (m = regex.exec(text)) {
    result.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(result); // => [ "One", "Test" ]

// Replacing words not preceded with ^ with some other text:
var regex = /([^\w^]|^)(\w+)/g;
console.log(text.replace(regex, '$1<SPAN>$2</SPAN>'));
// => <SPAN>One</SPAN> <SPAN>Test</SPAN>: ^Anotherword
```

The extraction and replacement regexps differ in the amount of capturing groups, as when extracing, we only need one group, and when replacing we need both groups. If you decide to use a regex with two capturing groups for extraction, you would need to collect `m[2]` values.

Extraction pattern means

- `(?:[^\w^]|^)` - a non-capturing group matching

  - `[^\w^]` - any char other than a word and `^` char
  - `|` - or
  - `^` - start of string
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars.

Comment: Wonderful! I will keep the other answer as the accepted answer since I asked for a non look behind solution though, and some people may be forced to use older javascript versions like I (thought I) was.

Comment: @TheCodingWombat The second snippet shows how to achieve what you needed without lookbehinds.